# Why won't getline function work multiple times in a for loop with an array of structures?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, for-loop, getline

I have a little problem. I've created a program that asks user to enter part's name and part's price for four diffrent parts. Each name and price fills a structure, and I have an array of four structures. When i do a for loop to fill all the names and prices, my getline functon doesn't work properly, it simply just skipps the entering part after I enter the first part's name. Can you please tell me why?
Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct part {
    std::string name;
    double cost;
};

int main() {

    const int size = 4;

    part apart[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        std::cout << "Enter the name of part № " << i + 1 << ": ";
        getline(std::cin,apart[i].name);
        std::cout << "Enter the price of '" << apart[i].name << "': ";
        std::cin >> apart[i].cost;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason the `getline` isn't prefixed by `std::`?

Comment: @Archimaredes it still doesn't work correctly even with `std::`

Comment: I wasn't implying it was the reason. I was just wondering.

Comment: @Mykola yeah, I figured out that i need to ignore one newline after `cin`. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::getline` consumes the newline character `\n`, whereas `std::cin` will consume the number you enter and stop.

To illustrate why this is a problem, consider the following input for the first two 'parts':

```
item 1\n
53.25\n
item 2\n
64.23\n
```

First, you call `std::getline`, which consumes the text: `item 1\n`. Then you call `std::cin >> ...`, which recognises the `53.25`, parses it, consumes it, and stops. You then have:

```
\n
item 2\n
64.23\n
```

You then call `std::getline` for a second time. All it sees is a `\n`, which is recognised as the end of a line. Therefore, it sees a blank string, stores nothing in your `std::string`, consumes the `\n`, and stops.

To solve this, you need to make sure the newline is consumed when you store the floating-point value using `std::cin >>`.

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
// required for std::numeric_limits
#include <limits>

struct part {
    std::string name;
    double cost;
};

int main() {

    const int size = 4;

    part apart[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        std::cout << "Enter the name of part № " << i + 1 << ": ";
        getline(std::cin,apart[i].name);
        std::cout << "Enter the price of '" << apart[i].name << "': ";
        std::cin >> apart[i].cost;

        // flushes all newline characters
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
}
```

Comment: I've already solved this problem by myself with a similar `cin.ignore`. But anyway, thanks!

Comment: The newline character in C++ is `'\n'` on **all** systems. The difference between Windows and Unix is in how that character gets written to a file and in what is treated as a the end of a line on input. But that's all irrelevant here: when you press `enter` on the terminal, the input functions see `'\n'`. There's no `'\r'` involved.

Comment: @PeteBecker Thanks - updated

Comment: (It's an honour, by the way!)

Comment: Your answer lays out the problem quite clearly. You might consider going on to what happens on the next extraction: in your example, after `getline` reads an empty line, `std::cin >> apart[i].cost;` will see the `'i'` in `"item 2"`, and the extraction will fail because that is not a valid representation of a floating-point value. That will set `std::cin` to a failed state, and any subsequent input attempts through `std::cin` will also fail. I've upvoted your answer; I don't think this addition is critical, and it might be too much of a distraction.